# Order Import or order creation via api

Tags: magento-enterprise, orders, api, magento-go

I have shifted my store from Magento Enterprise to Magento Go, now I need to require to import orders from enterprise to go but there is no functionality in magento for this and also I didn't find any extension for this.
So, I tried to use magento api to create order in go by taking order info from enterprise.
But I am getting following issues.

1. Api is not setting customer email id in newly created order via api.
2. If I tried to create an order on existing email, it is throwing exception and creating order as guest user only.
3. It is also throwing exception if it doesn't find same coupon code, payment method and shipping method.
4. How can I fetch customer id in magento go via api, as I needed it to create orders for registered customers.

How can I resolve all the above issues?

Comment: Is your problem still unsolved? If so, please add some code and the exact errors you get.

Comment: Sorry, this problem is not solved yet.

Comment: Regarding your problems, please add the exception messages you get as well as the code, which generates the errors.